# Iterating Pearsons R Correlation through all unique pairs

Tags: r

If I have an input file with 7 columns or an arbitrary number of columns, and each column has a number of values in it, and I want to run correlations for all unique pairs(where AB and BA are the same) of columns without having to go in and do `cor.test(column$A,
Column$B)` for every possible pair how do I do this in R?

Example data:

```
A    B    C    D
1    2    2    3
3    2    2    1
5    2    4    3 
5    2    3    3
```

In this case A, B, C,D are different columns and I would want to do all possible correlations for unique pairs where AB and BA count as the same pair, just as DA and AD would be the same pair.

Comment: Are you looking for `cor(mat)`? That returns the pairwise correlations of all columns of a matrix.

Comment: That sounds like it would work for my purposes. Would you be so kind as to provide an example of use? :)

Comment: @josilber - admittedly that gives a correlation, not a correlation test. But it is probably an appropriate starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
cor(df, use="complete.obs", method="kendall") #or whichever method fits you
```

or:

```
#this gives significance levels also
library(Hmisc)
rcorr(df, type="pearson") # type can be pearson or spearman

#or as matrix
rcorr(as.matrix(df))
```

If this doesn't work, try creating a list of column vectors and loop through everything (I will try to provide an example in edit)

Hope this helps